# How to print invoice in a particular format on a thermal printer

Tags: c#, graphics, printing, datagridview, printdocument

I am designing a software application for a Hotel. I want to print the invoice from a thermal printer and I want to print specific columns from the `DataGridView`. I have done most of the work but when name of item get larger then the string move out of the print area.

```
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
    Font font2 = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 10;
    int startY = 10;
    int offset = 40;
    graphic.DrawString("Welcome to Jaipur Rajwada", new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
    graphic.DrawString("Jaipur-Delhi Highway", new Font("Times New Roman", 9, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 15, startY + 18);

    int z = 1;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridViewSell.Rows)
    {
        string discription = dr.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString().PadRight(10);

        string price = string.Format("{0:c}", dr.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString());
        string quantity = dr.Cells[3].FormattedValue.ToString();
        string total = string.Format("{0:c}", dr.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString());
        string productline = z + " - " + discription + " - " + quantity + " - " + price + " - " + total;
        graphic.DrawString(productline, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX - 3, startY + offset);
        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
        z++;
    }
    offset = offset + 15;
    graphic.DrawString("Total to Pay".PadRight(20) + String.Format("{0:c}", textBoxTotal.Text), font2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);    
}

private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printReceipt();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your try catch is a bit redundant..

Comment: Well, you can calculate length of your string using `MeasureString` and do some text wrapping if it exceeds print area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print data in a particular format. So that it doesn't vanish mydesign while printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523688/how-to-print-data-in-a-particular-format-so-that-it-doesnt-vanish-mydesign-whi)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually check string length and do text wrapping.

Example:

```
string columnName = "...";
if(columnName.Length > 60)
{
    graphic.DrawString(columnName_part1, new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
    startY += 50;
    graphic.DrawString(columnName_part2, new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your Solution but its not working actually. What i want is to wrap only first part of the string i.e Description. Rest price and quantity will hold a position, as generally invoice have.

Comment: you may have fixed length for `Description` column only and do spacing if needed

Comment: thanks for your kind support but i am not able to divide string column name into two parts i.e column_part1,column_part2